# java fx titled border can not resolve

Tags: css, javafx, pane

i found topics with similar theme, but i couldn't resolve my issue.i have a small code for gui but i can not make my window to have that border and title in the smae line. the closest i got was border and just bellow title.Here is my code:

```
public class NumberAddition extends Application {

BorderedTitledPane root;
GridPane pane = new GridPane();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label first_lbl = new Label("First number: ");
    pane.setConstraints(first_lbl, 0, 0);
    Label second_lbl = new Label("Second number: ");
    pane.setConstraints(second_lbl, 0, 1);
    Label third_lbl = new Label("Result: ");
    pane.setConstraints(third_lbl, 0, 2);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Add");
    btn.setMinWidth(70);

    Button btn_1 = new Button();
    btn_1.setText("Clear");
    btn_1.setMinWidth(70);

    Button btn_2 = new Button();
    btn_2.setText("Exit");
    TextField txt_1 = new TextField();
    txt_1.setPrefWidth(200);
    pane.setConstraints(txt_1, 1, 0);
    TextField txt_2 = new TextField();
    txt_2.setPrefWidth(200);
    pane.setConstraints(txt_2, 1, 1);
    TextField txt_3 = new TextField();
    txt_3.setPrefWidth(200);
    pane.setConstraints(txt_3, 1, 2);

    HBox box = new HBox();
    pane.setConstraints(box, 1, 4);
    box.setPadding(new Insets(5, 50, 5, 50));
    box.setSpacing(50);

    box.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn_1);

    root = new BorderedTitledPane("Number addition");
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("bordered-titled-title.css").toExternalForm());
    root.getChildren().add(pane);

    pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    pane.setVgap(5);
    pane.setHgap(5);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(first_lbl, txt_1, second_lbl, txt_2, third_lbl, txt_3, box);

    // root.getChildren().add(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }  
   }



public class BorderedTitledPane extends StackPane{
BorderedTitledPane(String titleString) {
Label title = new Label(" " + titleString + " ");
title.getStyleClass().add("bordered-titled-title");
StackPane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

getStyleClass().add("bordered-titled-border");
this.getChildren().addAll(title);
  }

}
```

and css:

```
.label {
  -fx-font: 12px  sans-serif;
}

.bordered-titled-title {
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-translate-y: -16;
}

.bordered-titled-border {
  -fx-content-display: top;
  -fx-border-insets: 20 15 15 15;
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-border-color: black;
  -fx-border-width: 2;
}

.bordered-titled-content {
  -fx-padding: 26 10 10 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
 public class NumberAddition extends Application {
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label first_lbl = new Label("First number: ");
        pane.setConstraints(first_lbl, 0, 0);
        Label second_lbl = new Label("Second number: ");
        pane.setConstraints(second_lbl, 0, 1);
        Label third_lbl = new Label("Result: ");
        pane.setConstraints(third_lbl, 0, 2);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Add");
        btn.setMinWidth(70);

        Button btn_1 = new Button();
        btn_1.setText("Clear");
        btn_1.setMinWidth(70);

        Button btn_2 = new Button();
        btn_2.setText("Exit");
        TextField txt_1 = new TextField();
        txt_1.setPrefWidth(200);
        pane.setConstraints(txt_1, 1, 0);
        TextField txt_2 = new TextField();
        txt_2.setPrefWidth(200);
        pane.setConstraints(txt_2, 1, 1);
        TextField txt_3 = new TextField();
        txt_3.setPrefWidth(200);
        pane.setConstraints(txt_3, 1, 2);

        HBox box = new HBox();
        pane.setConstraints(box, 1, 4);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(5, 50, 5, 50));
        box.setSpacing(50);
        box.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn_1);

        pane.setVgap(5);
        pane.setHgap(5);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(first_lbl, txt_1, second_lbl, txt_2, third_lbl, txt_3, box);

        final String TITLE = "Number addition";
        Pane titledContent = new BorderedTitledPane(TITLE, pane);
        titledContent.setStyle("-fx-content-display: top;" + "-fx-border-insets: 20 15 15 15;"
                + "-fx-background-color: #eff1f4;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-border-width: 0.5;");
        titledContent.setPrefSize(pane.getMaxWidth(), pane.getMaxHeight());

        Scene scene = new Scene(titledContent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class BorderedTitledPane extends StackPane {
        BorderedTitledPane(String titleString, Node content) {
            Label title = new Label("  " + titleString + "  ");
            title.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #eff1f4;" + "-fx-translate-y: -10;");
            title.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
            StackPane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            StackPane contentPane = new StackPane();
            content.setStyle("-fx-padding: 20 5 5 5;");
            contentPane.getChildren().add(content);
            getChildren().addAll(title, contentPane);
        }
    }
}
```